# How to count inverse errors using COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to clean my formulas.

I favor using `FILTER` in my formulas. `FILTER` will return `#N/A` when it can not find any matches in a filter. And `COUNTA` includes `#N/A` errors in its count. So using this table with the following formulas.

| A |
| --- |
| foo |
| bar |
| baz |

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "foo"))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bar"))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "baz"))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "Gabriel"))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bog"))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "nit"))
=COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bug"))
```

All of the following formulas will return 1. Even if it doesn't find a match! The value will be one because it is counting the `#N/A`

The only work around I have found is doing something like this

```
=IF(IFERROR(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bog"), -1) = -1, 0, COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bog"))
```

This more than doubles the length of each formula I use this method on. In Excel I would just use `LET` but I need to use Google Sheets.

The closest I got to a solution is using `COUNTIF`

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "foo"), NA())
```

This returns the number of `#N/A`s in the list. Which would be 1 but I need something like

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "foo"), "<>"&NA())
```

which doesn't work. Oddly enough it does the exact same thing as the formula previous.

Comment: why not simply use `=COUNTIF(A1:A3,"foo")`?

Comment: As mentioned by @ztiaa I don't think you need to `FILTER` anything. This is taken care of using `COUNTIF`

Comment: I was trying to keep it simple guys, I will need to count more complex things. But I was trying to make my example repeatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `IFNA()` function to result in an empty cell, which `COUNTA()` doesn't count:

```
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "foo"),))
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bar"),))
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "baz"),))
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "Gabriel"),))
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bog"),))
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "nit"),))
=COUNTA(ifna(FILTER(A1:A3, A1:A3 = "bug"),))
```

[image: ex]